# Print line at particular line number from a file using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print a line at specific line number from a specified file using JavaScript.

Let's consider my external file (C:\temp.txt) has the following content:

`Apple
Ball
Cat
Dog
Elephant`

And my desired line number is 3, then the output of the javascript should be:

`Cat`

I came to know with file reader it is possible and searched a bit for the solution, but now sure how it is done.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Javascript:

```
//Using FileReader() Read by line
var lines = this.result.split('\n');
for(var lineNumber = 0; lineNumber < lines.length; lineNumber ++){
    console.log(lines[lineNumber]);
}
```

Working Sample: [jsfiddle.net/r4kt265b/1](http://jsfiddle.net/r4kt265b/1)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your reply, but I am not sure how can I put this in my code? As in, where can I specify the file and the line number? can you please elaborate? Thanks! _PS: I am new to JavaScript_

Comment: @PratikTalawadekar https://jsfiddle.net/r4kt265b/1

Please upload your text file and line by line will be printed in browser developer console. Feel free to edit this code for your requirement. Updated the answer with the working sample. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Mebin Joe, thanks for your effort. Your code from Fiddle works fine and I am already aware of this solution. But, I am specifically searching for a solution where the file will be provided as a path (might be hardcoded in the code) and not by user input. The file from the path can be stored at the client side or it can be on the server itself. And it should be in javascript. Please, can you help me with this specifically? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should have a back end for getting and reading the file. what is the backend you using?

Comment: I think you can't do it by using JS alone. Setting the path for an input element through Javascript is not possible, as a security measure. Or you can use fetch API

Comment: Hey Mebin, I am not sure what Back End you are talking about. But, I am building a Javascript included in the HTML code which prints the line at specific line number from another file to a `<div>` tag.

Comment: You mean you are using only HTML and JS, am I correct ?

Comment: Yes Mebin, just HTML and JS

Answer (score 0):

Node.JS example

```
let lines = [];
require('fs').readFileSync('temp.txt', 'utf-8').split(/\r? 
\n/).forEach(function(line){
   lines.push(line);
});
console.log(lines[2]);
```

Output:
Cat

Comment: With node.js it works, but when I include this as a javascript in html code, it won't work.. can you please help me with similar code in javascript?
This is how my code looks like: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myScript(){
 let lines = [];
 require('fs').readFileSync('temp.txt', 'utf-8').split(/\r?\n/).forEach(function(line){
    lines.push(line);
 });
 return lines[3].trim();
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myScript();
</script>

</body>
</html>
`
provided that `temp.txt` file resides in the same folder as of the code

Comment: NodeJS can not run in browser without a solution such as Webpack

Comment: Exactly Raymond! That's what I am saying. I really need a **Javascript** (_not node.js_) solution for my query.